# Show that $\{ \rho(u_n,v_n)\} \rightarrow \rho(u,v)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space in which $\{u_n\} \rightarrow u$ and $\{v_n\} \rightarrow v$.  show that $\{ \rho(u_n,v_n)\} \rightarrow \rho(u,v)$

I need to show that lim $\{ \rho(u_n,v_n), \rho(u,v) \} = 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: i was curious to know why is this question is vote down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the previous answers where deleted: That $u_n \to u$ in $(X,\rho)$ means that $\rho(u_n,u) \to 0$. Now we want to prove that $\rho(u_n,v_n) \to \rho(u,v)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. That is:

\begin{eqnarray}
\rho(u,v) &\leq& \rho(u,u_n)+\rho(u_n,v_n)+\rho(v,v_n) \\
&\leq & \rho(u,u_n)+\rho(u_n,u) +\rho(u,v) + \rho(v,v_n)+\rho(v,v_n).
\end{eqnarray}
Now taking the limit we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho(u,v) &\leq& \lim_{n\to\infty}\rho(u_n,v_n) \\
&\leq & \rho(u,v),
\end{eqnarray}
which finishes the proof.

---

Old answer:

\begin{eqnarray}
 \vert \rho(u_n,v_n)-\rho(u,v) \vert &\leq & \vert\rho(u_n,u) +\rho(u,v_n)-\rho(u,v) \vert\\
&\leq & \vert\rho(u_n,u) +\rho(u,v) + \rho(v,v_n)-\rho(u,v) \vert \\
&=& \vert\rho(u_n,u) + \rho(v,v_n) \vert \to 0. \end{eqnarray}

Here I used the triangle inequality for $ \rho $ two times and that the absolute value in $\mathbb{R}$ is continous.

### **This is wrong** since $a\leq b$ does not imply $|a-c| \le |b-c|$

Edited since the previous argument was slightly incorrect.